# Can I define a (typed) constant which is certain not to take up space in the executable?

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

I have a type `T` (for simplicity you may assume it's integral). I want to write some magic piece of code, after which I can use the identifier `foo` in any context in which I could use a value previous declared to have type `T` - with no necessary conversion. I also want decltype(T) to be `T`, and no less importantly - I want a *guarantee* that no space will ever be allocated for foo, it will only be relevant at compile time.

Is there a way to achieve this other than using `#DEFINE`? AFAICT, `constexpr const` isn't guaranteed to avoiding space allocation.

Comment: Unless something gets completely optimized away during compilation, everything used by a program has to exist in memory, somewhere. Whether it's the executable's data segment, or code segment, but it has to exist somewhere, and allocated in some form or fashion. Things just can't be floating in ether, somewhere, magically not taking up a single byte of memory, but somehow getting referenced and used in executable code. Computers don't work this way.

Comment: Just to be sure, writing a `constexpr` function `foo` returning a `T` is no solution? `decltype(foo())` would be `T`, nothing in the final binary once linkage have removed `foo`.

Comment: @user463035818: Typo, sorry.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: No. enums don't exist in memory, anywhere. Their _values_ may exist somewhere, e.g. as an operand to an instruction - but that's fine by me, because that's not my _header_ which adds to the executable's size, it's the person using it.

Comment: @YSC: Yes, sorry.

Comment: It's not going to be guaranteed by the standard perhaps, but realistically any production grade compiler is going to optimize out any constexpr variable that isn't ODR used. There's nothing stopping the compiler from just randomly wasting space either, so at the end of the day you either trust the compiler or you don't. This kind of thinking leads to macros or other nonsense, garbage code which "optimizes" something in theory but not in practice. Just add a constexpr variable, use it in some trivial way, and then compare the binary size to if you hardcode the number. It's going to be the same.

Comment: @NirFriedman I agree that there are some de-facto standards that almost every modern compiler follows. But still, C++ specification is written for a purpose. It is good to follow the rules and write code which behaves in the same way *no matter what*.

Comment: Thinking about it more, despite the fact that this question is positively received so far, IMHO this is just a fundamentally bad question, and should arguably be closed. Guarantees here, by definition, can only be offered by the C++ standard (and assuming a compliant compiler). But, the C++ standard simply doesn't talk about such low level details like executable size. So on very fundamental grounds, this question cannot be answered as written.

Comment: @NirFriedman Despite the title, OP in fact asks about *object allocation*. This term is in fact [extensively used by the doc](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek The C++ spec is 100% silent on things as low level as "binary size". Every compiler could in fact just dump a zero'ed block of 1KB at the end of its .o files, and still be a totally compliant compiler. Even asking this question assumes that compilers do not do conforming but totally inane things. There's just no point discussing it at the level of "guarantees" of the standard.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek This is just playing with words; OP wants to know if the variable has *space* allocated to it. The C++ standard does not say that object allocation implies that space needs to actually be allocated for it, and it doesn't prevent implementations from allocating space generally even if users haven't asked. There's no connection between these things.

Comment: "other than using #DEFINE" - I don't think that `#define` offers this guarantee either. AFAICT, a conforming compiler may bundle the sources with an interpreter and call it a day.

Comment: "enums don't exist in memory, anywhere" -- the enum ***definitions*** don't. But as soon as you use an enum value, in any way that's not completely optimized away, you have no choice but to pay for it, with bytes. Fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe give you no other option.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that, because standard does not force compilers to optimize anything. `constexpr` variables are *very likely* to be optimized if they are not [odr-used](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition).

If you can relax some of your requirements:

```
enum : T
{
  foo = some_value
};
```

Altough you create new type here, `std::underlying_type<>` will evaluate to `T` and you can use it without conversions where `T` is expected (with usual integer conversion rules). It also does not require function calling syntax (a `constexpr` function would be probably the best way to avoid space allocation, but it forces you to change the syntax from `T val = foo` to `T val = foo()`, which may or may not be acceptable).

Answer (score 0):

If writing a function is good enough, here is a minimal example:

```
struct T { int value; };

constexpr T foo() { return { 42 }; }

int main()
{
    return foo().value;
}
```

Compiled with `-std=c++17 -O3`:

```
main:
  mov eax, 42
  ret
```

The following condition is met:

```
#include <type_traits>
static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, decltype(foo())>);
```

Just to be clear, there is no guarantee whatsoever that your compiler and linker will remove the `foo` code from the final assembly, this is only highly probable.

However, it is guaranteed than the definition of function `foo` will only impact, if it does, the executable size and not the allocated storage.

Comment: Just because the compiler did optimize it away does not mean it must do so.  Can you cite where this behavior is mandatory? AFAIK this is only very likely to occur.

Comment: -1 for the assembly. We talk here about abstract C++ machine, not the GCC / Clang / whatever you used. C++ standard does not force compilers to optimize away storage allocation, even for `constexpr` variables. There is not guarantee and you proved nothing.

Comment: @NathanOliver of course I cannot. You know the Standard does not mandate anything about the binary representation. I'm just trying to help OP who looks more concerned about practical concerns than language guarantees.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek When OP shows concern about _executable size_ in their question/comment, I feel obligated to take a bit of distance with the C++ Standard and discuss more practical aspects in my answer, for instance the binary generated by common compilers. Is it worth a downvote?